Debugging (tracing) pgfplots sample point coordinates
Is there a way to debug (trace to the log file) coordinates of sample points or any intermediate calculations. For example, \addplot3 used below uses 3 points (0,0,2), (1,0,1) and (2,0,0) to draw the line. I'd like to see these coordinates in the log file or any other file.
I compile it using such commandline:
pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error DebuggingPgfPlot.tex

My sample DebuggingPgfPlot.tex file:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=150, view/v=20,
    axis lines=center, ticks=none, enlargelimits={abs=1.5cm}, axis on top]

% Line: y=0; z=-x+2, 0<=x<=2
\addplot3[
    blue,
    domain=0:2,
    samples=3,
    samples y=1, % curve
    declare function={
        CaclZ(\t)=-\t+2;
    }
]
({x}, {0}, {CaclZ(x)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I do not know if you can use x filter/.expression={nan} for anything. (I am not recommending it or anything - I am just giving the option as a point of consideration)
